# I made 2 files and in file 1, I have imported file 2

Tags: python

My import not works

I have made a python file name example1.py and another `example2.py` in `example2.py` I have imported `example1.py`. and I am getting the error.

```
from example1.py import a
print(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

remove `.py` extension in your import line. If both the files are in same directory, import it like this:

```
from example1 import a 
print(a)
```